# Adding red dot for means of each class in ggplot

Tags: r

I have the following basic plot.

```
ggplot(mpg) + 
geom_jitter(aes(x = class, y = hwy)) 
+   stat_summary(aes(x = class, y = hwy),fun=mean(), geom = “point”, color="red")
```

Im trying to add red dots for the means of hwy for each class.

But i am getting the following error:

```
Error: unexpected input in "+   stat_summary(aes(x = class, y = hwy),fun=mean(), geom = “"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the input showed,  the `+` is showed at the beginning of third line, while the command ended at 2nd line.  It should be at the end of second line.  Also, there was fancy quotes around the `point` and `fun = mean` is enough

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg) + 
   geom_jitter(aes(x = class, y = hwy)) +
   stat_summary(aes(x = class, y = hwy),fun=mean, geom = "point", color="red")
```

-output
[image]

Comment: Error: unexpected input in:
"    geom_jitter(aes(x = class, y = hwy)) +
    stat_summary(aes(x = class, y = hwy),fun=mean(), geom = “"

This is what i get when i run your code in RStudio